# couchdb view query based on multiple fieds

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchdb

I'm new to couchdb and stuck with one scenario. I have the following data.

```
{
_id:"1",
firstName: "John",
lastName: "John"
}
```

I am writing a view to return documents where firstName="John" or lastName="John" and have the following map. So, the query will be /view/byName?key="John"

```
function(doc){emit(doc.firstName, doc);emit(doc.lastName, doc);}
```

I can filter out the duplicates in reduce, however I am searching for a way to filter the documents in map.

Answer (score 0):

If by filter you mean get all unique values then reduce is the right way to do it. [Couchdb the definitive guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#unique) suggests this as well. Just create a dummy reduce

`function(key,values){return true;}`

and call your view with `?group=true`  and you will have all the unique results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have both documents in case of "John Smith" and "John Black", but "John John" should be reported once.

Couch gives you the unique set of keys with respect to keys ("John" in your example). Just emit the pair of name and document id (`[doc.firstName, doc._id]` and `[doc.lastName, doc._id]`) and reduce will do what you want.

```
["John", "ID_OF_SMITH"] != ["John", "ID_OF_BLACK"]
["John", "ID_OF_JOHNJOHN"] == ["John", "ID_OF_JOHNJOHN"]
```